# How to animate alpha in an image in Unity?

Tags: c#, image, animation, unity-game-engine, alpha

Ok, I don't know if this is possible but I need to animate the alpha portion of an image - like I have an image with a shape cut out of it so the background shows through, and I want to animate the size of this hole in Unity;s animation controller.

I know it is possible to animate images by stringing together a series of different images like sprite animation, but I want to know if there is a way to animate or cut a hole in another image using an image in Unity and/or animate the alpha portion.

Is this possible? An example of an alpha image with hole cut in it:

[image]

And I would want to scale/animate that cut out inner square.

Comment: How do you make that cut out inner square?, with a scrollview?, or it's an image with a hole in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I guess the **Shader** you can find [here](https://github.com/slavaobninsk/UIMask) will the closest answer to your question.

Other than that, operations on your texture will be quite heavy to perform at runtime.

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 1):

In unity, you can animate everything that can be changed in the inspector, including the size and color (including alpha) of your sprite.

However, it is not possible to animate pixels of a sprite seperately, as far as i know, meaning that you cannot change the alpha value of an area inside your sprite.

Do your images consist of a single color only or do you use complex images?